# Iterate XML in talend for missing child nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, talend

I am working to read the below mentioned XML input in talend open studio using tExtractXMLField.

```
<Outer>
<Account ID=1>
<Nominee>X</Nominee>
<Nominee>Y</Nominee>
</Account>
<Account ID=2>
<Nominee>Z</Nominee>
</Account>
<Account ID=3>
</Account>
</Outer>
```

I need to iterate on Nominees and capture the Account 3 even though there is no nominee tag in it. The output should be like one single table at grain of nominee but capturing the account even if there is no nominee.

```
Account ID | Nominee
1          |  X
1          |  Y
2          |  Z
3          | NULL
```

I am able to iterate the first 2 accounts successfully but, it misses the third one completely, as there is no nominee. As it is a real time scenario I can not break it into 2 jobs, so need to sort it in one subjob only.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I am not sure why down votes? I have explained my problem in detail. I have mentioned what i have tried so far.

Comment: Hey Mohit, 

Sorry for the downvotes but it is common with questions that seem to be asking for 'free work' also your explanation is not very clear next time please try to include a screenshot of your job and mention which components you are using this would give us a better idea on how to help and feels less like free work. 

In order to help can you please show what your Talend job looks like? not outputting a null value is common desirable functionality as that account is effectively an empty value what are you using to iterate on the Nominee?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following components, [tFileInputXML](https://help.talend.com/r/mjoDghHoMPI0yuyZ83a13Q/E3tQgEhQFdEfsQEMnfPGzg)

Use the **Account** tag, as **root**.

I leave you a link to the documentation, look at the scenarios, they indicate how to configure the element.

Regards.